# What is the meaning of "too much of a rub"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across [this phrase in a context](https://youtu.be/J2IwzcDl5tQ) where three people are discussing how best to sing the finale, and one says: *"If I sing the third is that too much of a rub?"* I can't figure out the meaning of *a rub* here.

According to [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rub), it can be interpreted as *a problem*, but the examples of the use given there look archaic. It's also mentioned as something that indicates a difficulty on [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+rub), though it's preceded there by `the`.

But then I thought, what if they're talking about *too much of a refinement or improvement*, like when you overdo it with spices in a kitchen? Is such an interpretation even possible? Or is the guy just asking if he's complicating things?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it might mean "is an interval of a third too dissonant there?"

Comment: *"There's the rub"* is a dated / dialectal expression meaning *"**That's** the problem!"* The fact that it's dialectal (appealingly "folksy", or "sub-standard", depending on preconceptions) is demonstrated buy the number of times written instances are *preceded by "**Ay**"* (dialectal / archaic "Yes, but..."). I've heard and used it myself "facetiously" many times, but I've *never* heard anyone extend it to anything like *"That's too much of a rub"*. Your best bet is to completely forget about this usage - it's no real use today.

Comment: Here are lots of written instances of [***Ay**, there's the rub.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ay+there%27s+the+rub%22) And plenty more spelt [***Aye,** there's the rub.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22aye+there%27s+the+rub%22) But don't use it today, and *please* don't get "creative" with things like *"It's nothing serious - just a bit of a rub"*.

Comment: It seems a fairly common US slang/casual term for an annoyance/irritation/problem. _It's the point where they try to exit the product that's been a bit of a rub," Keith Cox, the founder and chief executive of Vacatia, said in an interview._ (New York Times). I can see it as being annoying like a mild friction burn.

Comment: [Guy on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-definition-of-rub-in-slang-terms#:~:text=Mistake%20or%20Error%3A%20In%20some,%2C%20irritate%2C%20or%20bother%20someone.): _Mistake or Error: In some slang usage, "rub" can refer to a mistake, error, or blunder. For example, if someone says, "That was a real rub," they mean that something went wrong or there was a significant mistake._

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Not dialect - it's from the famous [To be or not to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be) speech from _Hamlet_!

Comment: My point being: formal/The Bard/old-fashioned: 'the rub'; informal/US slang: 'a rub'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: The [oldest relevant definition](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/rub_n1?tab=meaning_and_use) I see in the full OED is a full century before Shakespeare's use: ***1502– English regional (East Anglian).** A stone used for sharpening a scythe; a whetstone. Now rare.* Bizarrely, the OED cites Shakespeare's use as ***I** there's the rub* - so even my searches for ***Ay...*** and ***Aye...*** didn't cover all bases!

Comment: @FumbleFingers _I there's the rub_ seems bizarre indeed. However, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be) has a comparison of facsimiles of two quartos and the first folio, and the latter two seem to indeed have "I".